# Finding the limit of a nonlinear recursion sequence as $n$ goes to ∞

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, recursion, nonlinear

I want to find the limit as `n` goes to infinity of the nonlinear recursion sequence

```
x[n + 1] = x[n]/x[n - 1], x[-1] = 2, x[0] = 8]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eqn = {x[n + 1] == x[n]/x[n - 1], x[-1] == 2, x[0] == 8};
```

Using [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
soln = RSolve[eqn, x, n] // FullSimplify // Quiet;
```

Verifying that the solutions satisfy the equation and boundary conditions

```
eqn /. soln // FullSimplify

(*  {{True, True, True}, {True, True, True}}  *)
```

Only the first solution is real-valued

```
ComplexExpand[x[n] /. soln] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
Clear[solnR]

solnR[n_] = x[n] /. soln[[1]] // ComplexExpand // Simplify;
```

The min and max values are

```
{min, max} = (pts = {n, solnR[n]} /.
       Solve[{solnR'[n] == 0, -5 < n < 20}, n, Reals] // FullSimplify)[[All, 
    2]] // Union

(*  {4^(-Sqrt[7/3]), 4^Sqrt[7/3]}  *)

{min, max} // N

(*  {0.12032, 8.31116}  *)

pts[[All, 1]] // SortBy[#, N] & // Differences // FullSimplify

(*  {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}  *)
```

Hence, the function is periodic with a period of `6`. Verifying,

```
solnR[n] == solnR[n + 6] // FullSimplify

(*  True  *)

Plot[solnR[n], {n, -5, 20},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

So the limit is the interval

```
Interval[{min, max}]

(*  Interval[{4^(-Sqrt[7/3]), 
     4^Sqrt[7/3]}]  *)
```

Answer (score 4):

For convenience, let's translate the sequence to start from `n = 1`:

```
sol = x[n] /. 
 RSolve[{x[n + 1] == x[n]/x[n - 1], x[1] == 2, x[2] == 8}, x[n], n][[1]] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

The limit is undefined, and falls into an `Interval`:

```
lim = Limit[sol, n -> Infinity]
```

[image]

Evaluating the first 10 values of `sol`:

```
Table[sol /. n -> m, {m, 1, 10}]
```

> {2, 8, 4, 1/2, 1/8, 1/4, 2, 8, 4, 1/2}

yields the same numbers as

```
RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == x[n]/x[n - 1], x[1] == 2, x[2] == 8},  x[n], {n, 1, 10}]
```

Plotting the first 100 values obtained via `RecurrenceTable`:

[image]

shows 6 regularly alternating values. Hence, there is no limit in infinity for this recursive relation.